# When closing parent window, keep child window as new window

Tags: macos, swift, nswindow

I have an app with a overlay window, which covers the desktop with an semi-transparent background, then another window as a child window of that overlay window.

I want to be able to close the overlay window, but keep the child window.

I'm aware of the `close()` function for `NSWindow`s, but that would just close the overlay window.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "sub window" and "child window". I suspect you actually mean a view that's within the main window. "Child window" means something specific in Cocoa and I'm guessing it's not what you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

If you break the parent-child relationship before closing the parent, the child can remain. So, you'd do something like:

```
parent.removeChildWindow(child);
parent.orderOut(self); // or parent.close()
```